# capturing default tqdm output for unittesting

Tags: python, output, tqdm

How do I write a unit test to make sure that a tqdm progress bar has actually been called?  Also, how do i catch the output of the progress bar when i haven't specified the `file` kwarg (in which case it should default to `sys.stderr`)?

I tried using `contextlib.redirect_stderr` to catch the output, but that didn't work (see below for details).

Here's what i want to test. I have a method that sometimes uses a progress bar according to `self.use_progress_bar`. The object will get pickled for multiprocessing, so I can't have it own the progress bar.

```
def awesome_method(self):
    if self.use_progress_bar:
        progress_bar = tqdm.tqdm(total=self.match_generator.size,
                                 desc="Playing matches")

    if self.filename is not None:
        file = open(self.filename, 'w')
        writer = csv.writer(file, lineterminator='\n')

    for chunk in chunks:
        results = self._play_matches(chunk)
        self._write_interactions(results, writer=writer)

        if self.use_progress_bar:
            progress_bar.update(1)
```

I want to write a unit test that confirms the progress bar is there.  i tried something like:

```
import unittest
import MyAwesomeClass
from contextlib import redirect_stderr
import io

class TestMyCode(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_progress_bar(self):
        err = io.StringIO()
        with redirect_stderr(err):
            awesomeness = MyAwesomeClass(use_progress_bar=True)
            awesomeness.awesome_method()
        self.assertIn("Playing matches", err.getvalue())
```

but `err` is empty. The problem seems to be that if you don't instantiate tqdm with a file, it defaults to sys.stderr, but NOT the one in the context manager. when i tried running this:

```
def action():
err = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stderr(err):
    pbar = tqdm.tqdm(range(5))
    print('pbar: ', pbar.fp)
    print('err: ',err)
    print('stderr:', sys.stderr)
    pbar.update()
    pbar.update()
return err


if __name__ == '__main__':
    err = action()
    print('\nstart\n', err.getvalue(), '\nstop\n')
    print(sys.stderr)
```

this was the output (minus the pbar output which i couldn't capture):

```
pbar:  <colorama.ansitowin32.StreamWrapper object at 0x0000000002A18D68>
err:  <_io.StringIO object at 0x0000000002A8B318>
stderr: <_io.StringIO object at 0x0000000002A8B318>

start

stop

<colorama.ansitowin32.StreamWrapper object at 0x0000000002A18D68>
```

so, in the context manager (where the progress bar is instantiated), `sys.stderr` points to `err`, but the tqdm default of `self.fp = sys.stderr` is still grabbing the real `sys.stderr` even though it's in the context manager.  WHY?!?!?!? and how do I test for the progress bar **without** setting the `file=` on the tqdm object?

Comment: Were you specifically looking to capture & examine output of tqdm? If you just want to ensure tqdm is being invoked correctly based on self.use_progress_bar state, mocking tqdm might work. If so, I can write-up an answer.

Comment: @jleverenz no, i don't need stderr. i needed to know how many progress bars were created (should be 3) and ideally examine the first one created (check attributes `desc`, `total`, `n`, `disable`)  I would love to see a good example of a mock.